# TypeError: unbound method make_valid_name() must be called with User instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was migrating my old code from
flask sqlalchemy

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

to
sqlalchemy.orm - session maker

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
```

Model

```
@staticmethod
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id          = Column(Integer        , primary_key=True)
    name        = Column(String(20)     , unique=True, nullable=False)
.
.
.
    def make_valid_name(name):
        return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]', '', name)
```

Form

```
def validate(self):
.
.
.    
if self.name.data != User.make_valid_name(self.name.data):
                self.name.errors.append('Please use letters, numbers, dots and underscores only.')
                return False
```

While making a call to method self.validate() throws following error

```
TypeError: unbound method make_valid_name() must be called with User instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)
```

I am not sure what needs to be modified, how can i validate "self.name.data" From field data

Any help on this will be great.

Comment: Does `@staticmethod` appear in the code you omitted?

Comment: yes, its a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option was to create User object again and initialize attributes then pass that as parameter instead of form object name directly

```
user = User(
name = self.name.data
)

if self.name.data != User.make_valid_name(user):
```

and in model accessing same by

```
user.name
```

:@ have to rewrite everything.

Any other optimal solution will also be appreciated. If someone else faces similar issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

That error means `User.make_valid_name` is an instance method, not a static method as you expected. The solution, if you want to keep your existing usage, is to decorate the *method* with `staticmethod`, not the class:

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def make_valid_name(name):
        return ...
```

Alternatively, you can make it a `classmethod` instead:

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def make_valid_name(cls, name):
        return ...
```